# Can i upload Iphone App in testing mode

Tags: ios, iphone, iphone-developer-program

Can I upload the App in testing mode so that it can't available for normal user and i will change it to public mode later on. please help how to do so

Comment: do you know about TestFilght?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, you can either invite people as internal testers/team members - has a limit of 25 testers - and send them apps via testflight over app store connect, or you can upload your build and submit for review for beta testing, and then invite whoever you want as external testers - has a limit of 10.000 testers -. [For detailed info](https://developer.apple.com/testflight/)

Comment: in beta testing mode i will have the App link or not?

Comment: If you are referring to app store link, then the answer is no. The testers will get testflight mails with instructions for installing the app.

Comment: so App will visible to user or not?

Comment: it won't be visible to everyone except the ones you send the invitation via testflight